# What is damage window?

Tags: pokemon-go

On sliphroad's [site](https://thesilphroad.com/research) there's a section with moves pokemon could have. As with DPS, power and duration everything is clear, I've got no idea what Damage window means and how it affects battle. What is it? And why it varies from 0 to more that 2000? And why quick moves all have 200?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the amount of time in milliseconds at which you can get hurt by the attack, when fighting a Pokemon.

Thus you want to put Pokemon with attacks with bigger damage window, when defending gyms, so you'll be able to output more damage.

Comment: How does that work with Blizzard's 0?

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer Seams to be undodgeable https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/4t8up9/pokemon_go_attack_data_dps_energy_dodge_windows/

Comment: That link contradicts your answer.

Comment: @ИвоНедев your link makes sense. But it is still blurry, because I think I remember dodging blizzard yesterday

Comment: @MrCheatak I've yet to successfully dodge blizzard. I do dodge ice beams all the time, though.